# installing python 3.5 in virtaul env

Tags: python

I have already created a virtual env,in which python 3.4 is already installed,is there a way i can install python 3.5 in **this** env.i already tried pip install python3.5 ,i get -no distributions found that satisfy the requirement

Comment: Do you have Python 3.5 available on your system?

Comment: nope, only 2.7 and 3.4

Answer (score 2):

run `virtualenv -p python3 envname` or `pip install --upgrade virtualenv`

Comment: Throws a same-file error,when i run the second command i get the same errror described in my question

Comment: I found this helpful for me and am sure you will too. run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` if you don't have a `requirements.txt` file in your project.. then delete the virtual environment. recreate the virtual environment then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`... That' should work

Answer (score 2):

You should use `virtualenv` command once again, this time with new python executable as a parameter:

```
virtualenv env -p python3.5
```

(supposing you previously installed virtual env into folder named `env`).

As you don't pass `--clear` parameter, your previous files will be kept inside `env` dir

**Edit:**

If you want to to use within your virtualenv a python version not installed globally on your system and don't want to install new version of python globally, you can follow these steps:

1) download and compile required version of python (not installing it via `make install`)

2) pass the path to new python executable to the `-p` parameter of `virtualenv` command, like `virtualenv env -p /home/user/python3.5/python`

Comment: i get -`The executable python3.5 (from --python=python3.5) does not exist`

Comment: and you want to avoid installing python 3.5 globally?

Comment: Thank you for your time,i got around the problem without using env